# Solve a second order differential equation on R

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved this equation $x^2 y''(x)+y(x)=0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$, on $\mathbb{R}_-^*$ and I found :
$ f(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
   C_1 \sqrt{x} \sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}\ln(x)}{2})  + C_2 \sqrt{x} \cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}\ln(x)}{2})  &\text{ if } x>0\\
   C_3 \sqrt{-x}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}\ln(-x)}{2}) + C_4 \sqrt{-x}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}\ln(-x)}{2}) &\text{ if } x<0
 \end{cases}
 $

Now I have to solve it on $\mathbb{R}$, I studied the limit at $0$ of both solutions, it's $0$.
I suppose I have to check the derivative at 0 but it doesn't exist. So what can I conclude?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Even if $y''$ does not exist at $0$, it could happen that $x^2 y''$ has a removable discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: I understand what you mean but how I can introduce $x^2$ in my proof to say that my solution is correct on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to know what are the solutions of my equation on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is the limit as $x\rightarrow0$?

Comment: You should check for any removable singularities that $f$ and $f'$ have.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-}  f(x) = 0$ but f'(x) include a division by $\sqrt(x)$ so I don't know what do do.